# ipatool failed with an exception: #<RuntimeError: Nothing at path:

Tags: ios, xcode

when I try to distribute my app in Archives, I received the following exception.

```
   {
        code = 1067;
        description = "ipatool failed with an exception: #<RuntimeError: Nothing at path: /var/folders/56/_c0lpc_d187_r75j_0g9bmzw0000gn/T/IDEDistributionOptionThinning.~~~HTRS4v/Payload/DShop.app/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FBLazyVector/FBLazyVector/FBLazyIterator.h>\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2208:in `MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2261:in `block in MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `each'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2261:in `block in MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `each'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2261:in `block in MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `each'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2261:in `block in MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `each'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2261:in `block in MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `each'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2261:in `block in MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `each'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2261:in `block in MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `each'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2260:in `MakeFileSystemNode'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1877:in `initialize'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2982:in `new'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2982:in `ProcessIPA'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:3954:in `<main>'";
```

Could anyone help me?
Many thanks.

Comment: this may be because the way I rename my project is incorrect. So, I give up to rename the project,  just rename the Display Name and bundle ID, everything goes right.